# Wide to long format with several variables

Tags: r

This question is related to a previous question I asked on converting from wide to long format in R with an additional complication.

previous question is here: [Wide to long data conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596802/wide-to-long-data-conversion)

The wide data I start with looks like the following:

```
d2 <- data.frame('id' = c(1,2),
             'Q1' = c(2,3),
             'Q2' = c(1,3),
             'Q3' = c(3,1),
             'Q1_X_Opt_1' = c(0,0),
             'Q1_X_Opt_2' = c(75,200),
             'Q1_X_Opt_3' = c(150,300),
             'Q2_X_Opt_1' = c(0,0),
             'Q2_X_Opt_2' = c(150,200),
             'Q2_X_Opt_3' = c(75,300),
             'Q3_X_Opt_1' = c(0,0),
             'Q3_X_Opt_2' = c(100,500),
             'Q3_X_Opt_3' = c(150,300))
```

In this example, there are two individuals who have answered three questions. The answer to each question takes the following values {1,2,3} encoded in Q1, Q2, and Q3. So, in this examples, individual 1 chose option 2 in Q1, chose option 1 in Q2, and chose option 3 in Q3.

For each option there is also a variable X associated with each option that I also need to be converted to wide format.  The output I am seeking looks like the following:

```
    id question option choice cost
1   1        1      1      0    0
2   1        1      2      1   75
3   1        1      3      0  150
4   1        2      1      1    0
5   1        2      2      0  150
6   1        2      3      0   75
7   1        3      1      0    0
8   1        3      2      0  100
9   1        3      3      1  150
10  2        1      1      0    0
11  2        1      2      0  200
12  2        1      3      1  300
13  2        2      1      0    0
14  2        2      2      0  200
15  2        2      3      1  300
16  2        3      1      1    0
17  2        3      2      0  500
18  2        3      3      0  300
```

I have tried to adapting the code from the answer to the prior question, but with no success thus far.  Thanks for any suggestions or comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly elegant, but here's a tidyverse version:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d3 <- d2 %>% 
    gather(option, cost, -id:-Q3) %>% 
    gather(question, choice, Q1:Q3) %>% 
    separate(option, c('question2', 'option'), extra = 'merge') %>% 
    filter(question == question2) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(question, option), parse_number) %>% 
    mutate(choice = as.integer(option == choice)) %>% 
    select(1, 5, 3, 6, 4) %>% 
    arrange(id)

d3
#>    id question option choice cost
#> 1   1        1      1      0    0
#> 2   1        1      2      1   75
#> 3   1        1      3      0  150
#> 4   1        2      1      1    0
#> 5   1        2      2      0  150
#> 6   1        2      3      0   75
#> 7   1        3      1      0    0
#> 8   1        3      2      0  100
#> 9   1        3      3      1  150
#> 10  2        1      1      0    0
#> 11  2        1      2      0  200
#> 12  2        1      3      1  300
#> 13  2        2      1      0    0
#> 14  2        2      2      0  200
#> 15  2        2      3      1  300
#> 16  2        3      1      1    0
#> 17  2        3      2      0  500
#> 18  2        3      3      0  300
```

Comment: yes!  this works.  now to dig my head into understanding the steps better.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** First `melt` the input transformihg it to long form.  Then break apart the `variable` column on underscore using `read.table` giving columns named V1, V2, V3, V4 representing the question as a factor, junk, junk and the option parts, respectively. Append that back to `m` and set the question to the factor level of V1 and option to V4.  Sort it by `id` to give the same ordering as in the question.  (If the order does not matter this line could be omiited.)

Now put the parts together noting that choice is 1 if the appropriate column among the Q1/Q2/Q3 columns equals the option and 0 otherwise.

```
library(reshape2)

m <- melt(d2, id = 1:4)
m <- cbind(m, read.table(text = as.character(m$variable), sep = "_"))
m <- transform(m, question = as.numeric(V1), option = V4)
m <- m[order(m$id), ]
n <- nrow(m)
with(m, data.frame(id, 
   question, 
   option,
   choice = (m[cbind(1:n, question + 1)] == option) + 0, 
   value))
```

The result is:

```
   id question option choice value
1   1        1      1      0     0
2   1        1      2      1    75
3   1        1      3      0   150
4   1        2      1      1     0
5   1        2      2      0   150
6   1        2      3      0    75
7   1        3      1      0     0
8   1        3      2      0   100
9   1        3      3      1   150
10  2        1      1      0     0
11  2        1      2      0   200
12  2        1      3      1   300
13  2        2      1      0     0
14  2        2      2      0   200
15  2        2      3      1   300
16  2        3      1      1     0
17  2        3      2      0   500
18  2        3      3      0   300
```

**2)** This could also be expressed using magirttr giving the same answer.  Note that the last two pipes use the exposition operator `%$%` providing an implicit `with(., ...)` around the subsequent expression:

```
library(magrittr)
library(reshape2)

d2 %>%
   melt(id = 1:4) %>%
   cbind(read.table(text = as.character(.$variable), sep = "_")) %>%
   transform(question = as.numeric(V1), option = V4) %$%
   .[order(id), ] %$%
   data.frame(id, 
              question, 
              option, 
              choice = (.[cbind(1:nrow(.), question + 1)] == option) + 0, 
              value)
```

**3)** This can be translated to reshape2/dplyr/tidyr:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d2 %>%
   melt(id = 1:4) %>%
   separate(variable, c("question", "X", "Opt", "option")) %>%
   arrange(id) %>%
   mutate(question = as.numeric(factor(question)),
          choice = (.[cbind(1:n(), question + 1)] == option) + 0) %>%
   select(id, question, option, choice, value)
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This is very elegant.  I particularly like version 3).  Can you explain exactly what is happening in the line defining the choice variable.  This is the key line, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how it is working.  thanks.

Comment: `.[cbind(...)]` is the vector whose ith element is `.[i, question[i] + 1]`   See `?Extract` and in particular read the paragraph that starts with *A third form*. describing how R allows one to index an array by a matrix.