# Using pivot_longer from tidyr to create a long format data with one variable nested in another variable

Tags: r, tidyr

This is the edited version of the question.

I need help to convert my wide data to long format data using the `pivot_longer()` function in R. The main problem is wanting to create long data with a variable nested in another variable.

For example, if I have wide data like this, where

- variable `fu1` and `fu2` are variables for the follow-up (in days). There are two follow-up events (`fu1` and `fu2`)
- variables `cpass` and `is` are the results of two tests at each follow up

```
IDno <- c(1,2)
Sex <- c("M","F")
fu1 <- c(13,15)
fu2 <- c(20,18)
cpass1 <- c(27, 85)
cpass2 <- c(33, 90)
is1 <- c(201, 400)
is2 <- c(220, 430)
mydata <- data.frame(IDno, Sex, 
                     fu1, cpass1, is1, 
                     fu2, cpass2, is2)
mydata
```

which looks like this

[image]

And now, I want to convert it to long format data, and it should look like this:

[image]

I have tried the codes below, but they do not produce the data frame in the format that I want:

```
#renaming variables
mydata_wide <- mydata %>%
  rename(fu1_day = fu1,
         cp_one = cpass1,
         is_one = is1,
         fu2_day = fu2,
         cp_two = cpass2,
         is_two = is2)

#pivoting
mydata_wide %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(fu1_day, fu2_day),
    names_to = c("fu", ".value"),
    values_to = "day",
    names_sep = "_") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("cp_one", "is_one", "cp_two", "is_two"),
    names_to = c("test", ".value"),
    values_to = "value", 
    names_sep = "_")
```

The data frame, unfortunately, looks like this:

[image]

I have looked at some tutorials but have not found the best solution for this problem. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: How can there be `day` value `15` for `IDno`value `1` when in `mydata` there is no such value for that ID?

Comment: What do you mean by 'variable `test` is nested inside `fu`'?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, thanks for spotting the error. I have edited the question

Comment: @Julien, I removed the statement about nested - I think it is misleading and not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% # the "nested" pivoting must be done within two calls
  pivot_longer(cols=c(fu1,fu2),names_to = 'fu', values_to = 'day') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(starts_with('cpass'), starts_with('is')), 
    names_to = 'test', values_to = 'value') %>%
  # with this filter check not mixing the tests and the follow-ups
  filter(str_extract(fu,"\\d") == str_extract(test,"\\d")) %>% 
  mutate(test = gsub("\\d","",test)) # remove numbers in strings
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
   IDno Sex   fu      day test  value
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 M     fu1      13 cpass    27
2     1 M     fu1      13 is      201
3     1 M     fu2      20 cpass    33
4     1 M     fu2      20 is      220
5     2 F     fu1      15 cpass    85
6     2 F     fu1      15 is      400
7     2 F     fu2      18 cpass    90
8     2 F     fu2      18 is      430
```

I'm not sure if your example is your real expected output, the first dataset and the output example that you describe do not show the same information.

Comment: The codes from RobertoT work.  However, I would prefer (though not sure if it is possible) a solution without the need to use `filter()` and `mutate()`  (to avoid mixing the tests and the follow-ups). P/s I have also edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I took inspiration from almost similar post from [How to reshape Panel / Longitudinal survey data from wide to long format using pivot_longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398419/how-to-reshape-panel-longitudinal-survey-data-from-wide-to-long-format-using-p?rq=1) and from the solution provided by RobertoT and put together these codes:

STEP 1: Generate wide data for simulation

```
IDno <- c(1,2)
Sex <- c("M","F")
fu1_day <- c(13,15)
fu2_day <- c(20,18)
fu1_cpass <- c(27, 85)
fu2_cpass <- c(33, 90)
fu1_is <- c(201, 400)
fu2_is <- c(220, 430)
mydata_wide <- data.frame(IDno, Sex, 
                     fu1_day, fu1_cpass, fu1_is, 
                     fu2_day, fu2_cpass, fu2_is)
mydata_wide
```

[image]

STEP 1: CONVERT TO LONG DATA (`out1`)

```
out1 <- mydata_wide %>% 
  select(IDno, contains("day")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(fu1_day, fu2_day),
               names_to = c('fu', '.value'), 
               names_sep="_") 
out1
```

[image]

STEP 2: CREATE ANOTHER LONG DATA AND JOIN WITH `out1`

```
mydata_wide %>% 
  select(-contains('day')) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(IDno, Sex),
               names_to = c('fu', 'test'),
               names_sep="_") %>%
  left_join(out1)
```

The result looks like this

[image]